# Saving Category through API

Tags: categories

I'm trying to create a category through the api to import a load of datas,
but I'm stuck, the category won't be saved, and the saveCategory() method just returns *false*

```
$category = new CategoryModel();
$category->setContentFromPost(array(
    'groupId'       =>  $this->category_group_id,
    'title'         =>  $data[0],
    'colorCode'     =>  $data[1],
    'colorPreview'  =>  $data[2]
));
$category->enabled = true;
$res = craft()->categories->saveCategory($category);
```

Can I get a glimpse of what's happening, or the error ?

Is there anything wrong in this code ?
Does anyone have a good example/documentation for this ?

Thanks for your help.

Nicolas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get any validations errors on the category after you've attempted to save it with [`CategoryModel::getAllErrors()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/BaseModel#getAllErrors-detail) or [`\CModel::getErrors()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#getErrors-detail).

You're also setting the `groupId` on the Category's [`ContentModel`](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/ContentModel), but this property is actually on the Category record itself as it sets the relationship directly.

```
$category = new CategoryModel();
$category->groupId = $this->category_group_id;

$category->SetContentFromPost(array(
    'title' => $data[0],
    'colorCode' => $data[1],
    'colorPreview' => $data[2],
));

if (craft()->categories->saveCategory($category))
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    // dump the error messages
    Craft::dd($category->getAllErrors());
}
```

Comment: Hi Mike,  
thanks for the answer, this worked well to get all the errors.  
The title was causing the problem ("can't be null").  To fix it, I had to set the "title" property this ways :

    $category->getContent()->title = $data[0];

Is-it a normal behavior ?

Nicolas

Comment: Yes, the title and slug are defined on the ContentModel, so that different values can be stored for different locales.

Comment: What if I had to set different values for different locales of the custom fields ?